# c++ std::sort on vector of objects by attribute

Tags: c++, sorting

I have an object of type finalwords.
In it, two boolean variables,

```
bool isPopular;
bool isFirstSearch;
```

I'm trying to sort a vector of finalwords based on these attributes, but am having troubles sorting with more than one attribute involved.

I would like a list that is sorted in the following order:

```
isPopular=true, isFirstSearch = true
isPopular=true, isFirstSearch = false
isPopular=false, isFirstSearch = true
isPopular=false, isFirstSearch = false
```

In other words,

popular(1) and firstsearch(1) first,

followed by  popular(1) and firstsearch(0),

followed by popular(0) and firstsearch(1),

and lastly popular(0) and firstsearch(0)

```
void sortResults (vector <finalwords> &finalSuggestions)
{
  sort (finalSuggestions.begin(), finalSuggestions.end(), [] (finalwords x, finalwords y)
  {
    return ((x.isFirstSearch > y.isFirstSearch) && (x.isPopular > y.isPopular)) ;
  });
}
```

I know its not complete, but even with this, I have popular & firstsearch words in the middle/end of the vector. I'm having problems working backwards in the comparisons to get the desired order of the vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[] (const finalwords& x, const finalwords& y)
{
    if (x.isPopular != y.isPopular) return x.isPopular;
    else if (x.isFirstSearch != y.isFirstSearch) return x.isFirstSearch;
    else return false;
}
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/NOBWJ2501)

Comment: Works now, would never have thought of != comparisons! Thanks, +1 for demo

Comment: The second condition `else if (x.isFirstSearch != y.isFirstSearch)` is **not** really needed. You could just write `else return x.isFirstSearch; `

Comment: @Nawaz I just want to return `false` when they are identical, because it should implement `<` logic, right?

Comment: @songyuanyao: If they're identical, then returning `false` makes as much sense as returning `true`. If that is so, then `else return x.isFirstSearch;` is enough, as it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison function is not correct, as it doesn't implement [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) as required by sorting. It should be written as:

```
[] (finalwords const & x, finalwords const & y) //use const &
{
   if ( x.isPopular!= y.isPopular) 
        return x.isPopular;
    else
        return x.isFirstSearch;
}
```

which basically says, if `x.isFirstSearch` and `y.isFirstSearch` are not equal, then return `x.isFirstSearch` because if `x.isFirstSearch` is `true` (which means the other is `false`). then `x` must come before `y`, Or if `x.isFirstSearch` is `false` (which means other is `true`), `x` must come after `y`. The same reasoning for `else` block as well.

Read more about *strict weak ordering*:

[What is meaning of strict weak ordering in layman's term?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585396/what-is-meaning-of-strict-weak-ordering-in-laymans-term)

Note that `std::tuple` implements strict weak ordering, so you could just write this:

```
[] (finalwords const & x, finalwords const & y) //use const &
{
   return std::make_tuple(x.isPopular, x.isFirstSearch) < std::make_tuple(y.isPopular, y.isFirstSearch);
}
```

That does the same work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While I am still soaking in how this works, I will point out that it is flipping condition #2 and #3 above. This sort does #1, #3, #2, #4

Comment: I understand that `isFirstSearch` and `isPopular` are boolean values... But for the sake of the programmer reading the code, couldn't we keep the explicit less than comparison: https://gist.github.com/sharth/ad57ee268ef1205b67bf

Comment: @filposs: If you want to compare `isPopular` first, then do that first (see my answer again). As for how it works, try using few pairs of values, then run this code in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

It's arguably a little cryptic - as it utilises implicit conversions from `bool` to `0` or `1` - but just for the fun of listing another alternative:

```
return lhs.isPopular * -2 - lhs.isFirstSearch <
       rhs.isPopular * -2 - lhs.isFirstSearch;
```

This is basically giving weightings to the fields, and summing those to get a weighting for the object: they're negative to get `true` values earlier in the ordering, and `isPopular` has double the "weight" of `isFirstSearch` so it is the "primary" sort field.  This happens to avoid branching too, so may perform differently (likely better) than `if` / `else` or `?` / `:`-using alternatives, though that's not likely to matter often.